# Matplotlib histogram with errorbars

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I have created a histogram with `matplotlib` using the `pyplot.hist()` function. I would like to add a Poison error square root of bin height (`sqrt(binheight)`) to the bars. How can I do this?

The return tuple of `.hist()` includes `return[2]` -> a list of 1 Patch objects. I could only find out that it is possible to add errors to bars created via `pyplot.bar()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Indeed you need to use bar. You can use to output of `hist` and plot it as a bar:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

data       = np.array(np.random.rand(1000))
y,binEdges = np.histogram(data,bins=10)
bincenters = 0.5*(binEdges[1:]+binEdges[:-1])
menStd     = np.sqrt(y)
width      = 0.05
plt.bar(bincenters, y, width=width, color='r', yerr=menStd)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to have this implemented in hist(). So that it calculates the std automatically for each bin.

Answer (score 9):

#### Alternative Solution

You can also use a combination of `pyplot.errorbar()` and `drawstyle` keyword argument. The code below creates a plot of the histogram using a stepped line plot. There is a marker in the center of each bin and each bin has the requisite Poisson errorbar.

```
import numpy
import pyplot

x = numpy.random.rand(1000)
y, bin_edges = numpy.histogram(x, bins=10)
bin_centers = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])

pyplot.errorbar(
    bin_centers,
    y,
    yerr = y**0.5,
    marker = '.',
    drawstyle = 'steps-mid'
)
pyplot.show()
```

#### My personal opinion

When plotting the results of multiple histograms on the the same figure, line plots are easier to distinguish. In addition, they look nicer when plotting with a `yscale='log'`.

Comment: The `fmt='none'` option in `pyplot.errorbar` will enable you just plot the error bars.