# How to plot a histogram for all unique combinations of data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, seaborn

- Is there a way I can get a size frequency histogram for a population under different scenarios for specific days in python

  - means with error bars
- My data are in a format similar to this table:

```
SCENARIO     RUN     MEAN     DAY
A             1       25       10
A             1       15       30
A             2       20       10
A             2       27       30
B             1       45       10
B             1       50       30
B             2       43       10
B             2       35       30
```

- `results_data.groupby(['Scenario', 'Run']).mean()` does not give me the days I want to visualize the data by

  - it returns the mean on the days in each run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)

- FactGrid is a Multi-plot grid for plotting conditional relationships
- Map [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) onto the FacetGrid and use `hue=DAY`.

## Setup Data and DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random  # just for test data
import numpy as np  # just for test data


# data
random.seed(365)
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'MEAN': [np.random.randint(20, 51) for _ in range(500)],
        'SCENARIO': [random.choice(['A', 'B']) for _ in range(500)],
        'DAY': [random.choice([10, 30]) for _ in range(500)],
        'RUN': [random.choice([1, 2]) for _ in range(500)]}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

### Plot with `kde=False`

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='RUN', row='SCENARIO', hue='DAY', height=5)
g = g.map(sns.distplot, 'MEAN', bins=range(20, 51, 5), kde=False, hist_kws=dict(edgecolor="k", linewidth=1)).add_legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Plot with `kde=True`

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='RUN', row='SCENARIO', hue='DAY', height=5, palette='GnBu')
g = g.map(sns.distplot, 'MEAN', bins=range(20, 51, 5), kde=True, hist_kws=dict(edgecolor="k", linewidth=1)).add_legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Plots with error bars

- Using [how to add error bars to histogram diagram in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390276/how-to-add-error-bars-to-histogram-diagram-in-python/35390513#35390513)
- Using `df` from above
- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) to plot the error bars on the histogram.

```py
from itertools import product

# create unique combinations for filtering df
scenarios = df.SCENARIO.unique()
runs = df.RUN.unique()
days = df.DAY.unique()
combo_list = [scenarios, runs, days]
results = list(product(*combo_list))  

# plot
for i, result in enumerate(results, 1):  # iterate through each set of combinations
    s, r, d = result
    data = df[(df.SCENARIO == s) & (df.RUN == r) & (df.DAY == d)]  # filter dataframe
    
    # add subplot rows, columns; needs to equal the number of combinations in results
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i)
    
    # plot hist and unpack values
    n, bins, _ = plt.hist(x='MEAN', bins=range(20, 51, 5), data=data, color='g')
    
    # calculate bin centers
    bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])
    
    # draw errobars, use the sqrt error. You can use what you want there
    # poissonian 1 sigma intervals would make more sense
    plt.errorbar(bin_centers, n, yerr=np.sqrt(n), fmt='k.')


    plt.title(f'Scenario: {s} | Run: {r} | Day: {d}')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: great class!:) @TrentonMcKinney