# How to get error bars on barchart PowerBI?

Tags: statistics, powerbi, bar-chart

I want to have such barchart:

[image: Desired bar chart]

The error bar on each column should show dispersion (I have it calculated in one of the columns). And top lines show whether there is a significant difference. Right now I have only achieved such graph:

[image: achieved bar chart]

I am using simple clustered barchart in PowerBI Desktop. Maybe there is another visual for that or another program which could do it? Maybe Python somehow?

Comment: I finally made it with excel, using this Microsoft tutorial: "Add, change, or remove error bars in a chart": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-change-or-remove-error-bars-in-a-chart-e6d12c87-8533-4cd6-a3f5-864049a145f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774822/matplotlib-histogram-with-errorbars) you can do that with `matplotlib` from python. Just as an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

data       = np.array(np.random.rand(1000))
y,binEdges = np.histogram(data,bins=10)
bincenters = 0.5*(binEdges[1:]+binEdges[:-1])
menStd     = np.sqrt(y)
width      = 0.05
plt.bar(bincenters, y, width=width, color='r', yerr=menStd)
plt.show()
```